# What does "penned down" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does **"penned down"** mean in the below?

If it's the past form of the verb "pen" then I couldn't find any particular meaning of "pen". I came across a sentence:

> Don't worry if you are single, trust on destiny and remember destiny has **penned down** for you a lovely soulmate. Just be patient. Till then keep improving.

Could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Maybe the writer is referring to fate - "it is written".

Comment: so is that related to pen.like we use pen for writing.so in that context..something like that?

Comment: Possibly. You haven't really given us enough context. It's just my best guess. A longer quote would help. But, yes, *penned* as in *written*.

Comment: It could mean *penned* as trapped in a *pen* (cage or fenced area). We really need more information - the source or a longer quote.

Comment: i updated full sentence

Comment: My first guess was correct.

Answer (score 5):

I understand it to mean "written down". You would more often see something like "I penned down a quick note". In the context of destiny writing something down for you, it seems a bit odd to me, but I guess the intention was poetic.

Comment: You could also note that it is just bad writing. The imagery doesn't work well (destiny may be able to write down a name, but can't write down a person), and there is the confusing combination of "written down", "put in a pen" and "pinned down". Also, say "trust in". The adjective "lovely" is weak. And the advice is unclear (improving at what?)

Answer (score 1):

The writing isn't the best quality but it is common to imagine destiny taking the form of a book (Arabic has a word for it, Maktub). What the writer is suggesting, is that if God (or the universe) plans for you to meet your soulmate in a few year's time, you should be patient and work on being a better person for that time.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a misspelling. It should probably be "pinned down" as one sticks a pin in something to fix it in place. See [macmillandictionary.com: Pin Down](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pin-down)

Answer (score -1):

You pencil in a tentative appointment.
You pen down a confirmed appointment.